# Sending token by POST or cookie?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, web

I've got a single page node.js FB Canvas App. Every user action triggers an AJAX POST to my node.js HTTPS server, returning the result.

Now I need a way to send a user token I create from the userId on app boot (this is an AJAX POST too, returning all content + user token). I verify that it is this user by doing a Graph API call (which is required for my boot for another reason) on the server.

Q1 So to create the token what should I use?

Q2 How to send the token with every AJAX call:

1. POST param?
2. cookie?
3. something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1** I assume that tokens should be unique and secure. That's generally not an easy problem. I would go with following steps:

1. generate a random number
2. try to save it into DB (or any other shared storage)
3. if it already exists in DB go to step 1. if not go to step 4
4. send the token

Ad.1. To generate a random number use `crypto.randomBytes` with large enough `size` param (256 is more then enough) in order to minimize collisions:

http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback

`crypto.randomBytes` should be secure. There are however some subtleties with it. For example you have to ensure that your machine has enough entropy. It can be a problem when your server does not have keyboard, mouse or mic. You can always add a hardware entropy generator:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

If you don't need it to be secure then you can use `crypto.pseudoRandomBytes` instead.

Also it is a good idea to create and use your own algorithm (based on `crypto` of course). For example add a current date to that number, hash it, whatever. Just be careful not to overdo it.

Also remember about cleaning DB from old tokens.

**Q2** It doesn't really matter. Whatever suits you. Probably putting it in a cookie is the easiest solution.

Comment: @aremie Both of us probably don't know what they use (if anything) to create entropy so I guess that you should ask them. Unless security is not an issue.

Comment: it is. I'll ask them, thanks for the good answer. Pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this token for preventing from a CSRF attack, I'd recommend to send it into a POST parameter.

Comment: I'll do the POST param!